# Making sense of complex derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Am reading chapter 2 in Sarason's Complex Function Theory book and am really confused about the material.

**Definition**. A complex function $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ defined on an open set $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ is said to be differentiable at $z_0\in G$ if there exist a $c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$$ \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R(z)}{z-z_0}=0$$

where $R(z)=f(z)-f(z_0)-c (z-z_0)$.

**Definition.** A function $u:G\to\mathbb{R}$ defined on an open set $G\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is said to be differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)\in G$ if there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} \frac{R(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}=0$$

where $R(x,y)=u(x,y)-u(x_0,y_0)-a(x-x_0)-b(y-y_0)$.

So far so good. But now on p.15 Sarason writes "to facilitate a comparison with complex differentiation, we restate the preceding definition in complex notation" and then gives

**Definition.** A function $u:G\to\mathbb{R}$ defined on an open set $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ is said to be differentiable at $z_0=x_0+i y_0 \in G$ if there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R(z)}{z-z_0}=0$$

where $R(z)=u(z)-u(z_0)-a(x-x_0)-b(y-y_0)$.

**Question 1**: Where is the absolute value in the denominator?

Next, Sarason writes

Let $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ be defined on an open set $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ and let $u$ and $v$ denotes its real and imaginary parts, so that $f=u+i v$. Given a point $z_0=x_0+iy_0 \in G$ and a complex number $c=a+bi$ we can write

$$R(z)=f(z)-f(z_0)-c (z-z_0)= \big[ u(z)-u(z_0)-a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0) \big]+ i \big[ v(z)-v(z_0)-b(x-x_0)-a(y-y_0) \big] = R_1(z)+i R_2(z)$$

Then comes the statement

"Clearly $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R(z)}{z-z_0}=0$ if and only if $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R_1(z)}{z-z_0}=0$  and $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R_2(z)}{z-z_0}=0$ ".

Finally Sarason concludes "$f$ is differentiable (in the complex sense) at $z_0$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are differentiable (in the real sense) at $z_0$".

**Question 2:** Why is the iff statement true? If $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)+g(x) = 0$ we don't necessarily have $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=0$ so I don't know how to obtain the "only if" part. The "if" part is ok, but in any case the definition of real differentiability of  $u$ is

$$ \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R_1(z)}{\lvert z-z_0 \rvert}=0$$ and not

$$ \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{R_1(z)}{z-z_0}=0$$

And I don't see why these two should be equivalent.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Alphie, a couple of things that will help you: First $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} g(z)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}| g(z)|=0$. Therefore $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} g(z)=c$ if and only if $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} |g(z)-c|=0$. This helps you figure your first question. For your second question, notice that if $f,g$  are real valued then $f(x,y)+i g(x,y)\rightarrow a+i b$ iff and only if $f(x,y)\rightarrow a$ and $g(x,y)\rightarrow b$ ( $a,b$ are real numbers of course).

Comment: You should correct the negative sign under the square root that gives the Euclidean distance in the second definition.

Comment: @Medo Thanks for the first question! But for the second question we have $\frac{R(z)}{z-z_0}=\frac{R_1(z)}{z-z_0}+i\frac{R_2(z)}{z-z_0}$ but $\frac{R_1(z)}{z-z_0}$ and $\frac{R_2(z)}{z-z_0}$ are not real-valued because of the complex denominator.

Comment: @Medo I corrected the sign thank you.